# File not found exception when using fileinput/output stream

Tags: android

I have this warning in my LogCat when I open up my app:

```
12-05 16:45:10.426: W/System.err(12045): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget/files/bitmapA (No such file or directory)
12-05 16:45:10.426: W/System.err(12045):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
12-05 16:45:10.426: W/System.err(12045):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
12-05 16:45:10.426: W/System.err(12045):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:80)
12-05 16:45:10.426: W/System.err(12045):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:463)
12-05 16:45:10.426: W/System.err(12045):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput   (ContextWrapper.java:152)
12-05 16:45:10.426: W/System.err(12045):    at com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.GridViewAdapter.getView(GridViewAdapter.java:71)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1428)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:935)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8541)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8541)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8541)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8541)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3257)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8541)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:903)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1961)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4333)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-05 16:45:10.436: W/System.err(12045):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This occurs because it is running my coding for the fileinputstream before I want it to.

To give some background, I have a checkbox that creates a bitmap when checked and then saves that bitmap to internal memory by doing this:
(this is where I save it)

```
addCheckbox
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (addCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                        System.out.println("Checked");
                        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
                        Drawable icon = null;
                        try {
                            icon = pm
                            .getApplicationIcon(entry.activityInfo.packageName);
                        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Drawable default_icon = pm.getDefaultActivityIcon();
                        if (icon instanceof BitmapDrawable
                                && default_icon instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                            BitmapDrawable icon_bd = (BitmapDrawable) icon;
                            Bitmap icon_b = icon_bd.getBitmap();
                            BitmapDrawable default_bd = (BitmapDrawable) pm
                                    .getDefaultActivityIcon();
                            Bitmap default_b = default_bd.getBitmap();
                            if (icon_b == default_b) {
                                // It's the default icon
                                scaleDownBitmap(default_b, 100, v.getContext());
                                Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Scale Bitmap Chosen");

                                SaveImage(default_b);
                                Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Scaled BM saved to External Storage");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), GridViewAdapter.class);
                                // intent.hasExtra("bitmapA");
                                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                Log.d("AppInfoAdapter", "Intent started to send Bitmap");

                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Un-Checked");
                    }

                }
            });
```

saveImage class:

```
    public void SaveImage(Bitmap default_b) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 100000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n +".png";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    Log.i("AppInfoAdapter", "" + file);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        // File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            //  + "/" + fname + ".png");
        FileOutputStream out = mContext.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("bitmapA", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        // FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        default_b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and then I get that bitmap from a filestream in another class here:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(Context);
        Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "new imageView added");
    }
    try {
        Bitmap bitmapA = null;
        FileInputStream in = Context.openFileInput("bitmapA");
        bitmapA = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
        /*BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        byte[] bitMapA = new byte[buf.available()];
        buf.read(bitMapA);
        Bitmap bM = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitMapA, 0, bitMapA.length);
        */view.setImageBitmap(bitmapA);
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        /*if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
        }*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    return view;
}
```

As a result of all of this, when I check the checkbox, it doesn't create the bitmap THEN save it to memory THEN get it from memory and set it into the imageView. All my checkbox does is print out "Checked" (like it's supposed to though)

Why is this?

Please note that both classes extend base adapter

Answer (score 0):

Did you made sure your app has write permission to the disk?

Comment: Yes, I have the permission